Is this a sign of a leaking roof?
Every time it rains heavily I see a puddle of water forming near the wall near outside the front door. Is this something with the roof or gutter? Thanks in advance.
Pictures:
https://imgur.com/a/6tMDtQu

Probably the roof has a leak.  Finding the exact location can be hard unless you can check the roof deck from underneath.  Water travels.  The gutters should not cause the leak, but will not help either if leaking/blocked.
